# 'telephoned' vs 'did telephone'

Tags: questions

> Somebody telephoned Emma.

What is correct form if I want to ask a question?

> Who **telephoned** Emma?

vs

> Who **did telephone** Emma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/telephone), **telephone** can in principle be used as a verb, but as this [NGRAM](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I%20called%20him%20yesterday%2C%20I%20phoned%20him%20yesterday%2C%20I%20telephoned%20him%20yesterday&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20called%20him%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20phoned%20him%20yesterday%3B%2Cc0) shows, **call** and **phone** are a lot more common.

> Who called Emma?

would be the most widely used of your two sentences.  When you have a question word like **who** for the subject, it is not necessary to do an subject-auxiliary verb inversion. It is only necessary to insert **do** if inversion is required and there isn't already an auxiliary verb.

While **did** is not necessary, it can be added for emphasis: for example:

> A: **Did** John call Emma? - *inversion required because there is no question-word, and there is no auxiliary verb, so **did** must be added*
>   B: No.
>   A: Well, who **did** call Emma? - ***did*** is optional, for emphasis

Note that, if the question word represents the object, however, you do need to do subject-auxiliary inversion:

> Who did you call? - *you is subject, must be inverted with **did***

Answer (score -2):

Both sentences are grammatically correct but imply different meanings.

> Who telephoned Emma?

- you enquire about the person who made a call to Emma (Someone made a call to Emma, "Who" is a subject)

> Who did telephone Emma?

- you ask which person did Emma call (Emma made a call, Emma is a subject)

Comment: No, the second claim is completely wrong. _Who did telephone Emma_ is unequivocally asking about the person who made the call to Emma. The difference is only one of emphasis - the version with _did_ suggests something like "I thought it was X that telephoned Emma, but if it wasn't, then who was it?_

Comment: This is incorrect.  Emma is the object of the verb in both cases, the recipient of the telephone call.